# how to make word to pdf with vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

i want make a sub

```
Sub Word2pdf(document As document)
    Dim objApp As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Object
    Set doc = Documents.Open(Filename:=document.Name)
    doc.ExportAsFixedFormat document.Name & ".pdf", wdExportFormatPDF
    doc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=document.Name, _
            ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
            wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
            Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
            CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
            BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
    MsgBox "word 2PDF file finished！"
End Sub
```

Comment: Whats the issue you are having?

Comment: i think not running

Comment: But whats the error and on which line is the error being thrown?

Comment: no registe classes

Comment: In what application is this code running? It declares an object for the `Word.Application` but never instantiates it. This is done when the code is *not* running *in Word*, but somewhere else. In that case, the code will fail because the Word.Application is not being instantiated. If a document object is being passed to the procedure, what is it for, since the code is opening a document? You need to more precisely (and understandably) describe what you need to do and how the code is failing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question, but the following revised code is working here:

```
Sub Word2pdf(docName As String)
    Dim doc As Object
    Set doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=docName)
    doc.ExportAsFixedFormat docName & ".pdf", wdExportFormatPDF
    MsgBox "word 2PDF file finished!"
End Sub
```

This creates a PDF with a file ending that reads **.docx.pdf**, so you might want to do a little string manipulation to get rid of the .docx

Comment: want use to “doc、docx”

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what your reply means. Normally a PDF would end with just ".pdf", without .docx in front of it.